# Get records that are only numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this query running.  For the most part it works ok, but there are a few records that have non-number parts to them and this causes issues down the line.  I need to be able to select just the records that are integers.

```
select distinct SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5) AS STUDY_NUMBER
        FROM         dbo.PA01201 AS PA01201_1
        where PAPROJNUMBER>'0'
```

For example, a part of the result list looks like this:

```
68145
68146
68147
7762A
99999
LABOR
```

i want all of those except 7762A and LABOR.  How can I modify the where clause to achieve that efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding '.0e0' to the substring will insure that the ISNUMERIC only returns valid integers.

```
select distinct SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5) AS STUDY_NUMBER
    FROM dbo.PA01201 AS PA01201_1
    where PAPROJNUMBER>'0'
        AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5) + '.0e0') = 1
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Appending '.0e0' causes decimal numbers to fail the ISNUMERIC check because there is an additional decimal point, and causes numbers in scientific notation (e.g. floating point) to fail because of the doubled exponent. Consequently, this elegantly excludes non-integer cases and ensures your substring will be a numeric integer.

Comment: +1 - Efficient way to bypass the unexpected positives in `ISNUMERIC()`

Comment: +1 for including a solution that only returns true for integers. I've found ISNUMERIC to be useless without additional checks. See the IsInteger function located at http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423

Comment: +1 to @AndriyM. .0 should be enough for an integer check. I'm curious as to any benefits or caveats associated with .0 over .0e0. Using the examples from http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423, all of the following return false: Select IsNumeric('$12.09' + '.0');
Select IsNumeric('1.4e3' + '.0');
Select IsNumeric('2d4' + '.0');
Select IsNumeric('3.7' + '.0');

Comment: @AndriyM & Brian '.0' is *NOT* sufficient. As an example '+$.0' will still return 1 while '+$.0e0' will return 0.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: Agree, same goes about just `+` or just `$`. Either way, it's a pity that neither `.0` nor `.0e0` will catch an empty string: `ISNUMERIC` would return `1` in either case.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: It is likely, however, that `.0` would be enough in *this* particular case, as, depending on the collation, `'+'` and `'$'` might go before `'0'`, and so the `PAPROJNUMBER>'0'` part of the filter would filter those cases out.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5) AS STUDY_NUMBER
FROM dbo.PA01201
WHERE SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5) LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: I wonder if rewriting the WHERE clause this: `WHERE PAPROJNUMBER LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'` – would render the query sargable. (+1 anyway)

Answer (score -2):

Add ISNUMERIC() to your where clause:

```
select distinct SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5) AS STUDY_NUMBER
from DBO.PA01201 AS PA01201_1
where PAPROJNUMBER > '0' AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5))
```

Alternatively, you can drop the `>` comparison:

```
select distinct SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5) AS STUDY_NUMBER
from DBO.PA01201 AS PA01201_1
where ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(PAPROJNUMBER, 1, 5))
```

Comment: Note that there are issues with using ISNUMERIC alone. As examples, an empty string, '+' and '$' will all return 1. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8581894/341251) for a safer alternative.